# sending multiple types of Runnable Tasks to Executorservice

Tags: executorservice, countdownlatch

Suppose we have tow types of Task classes( First and Second )implementing Runnable. both of them have an access to a shared object (syncObj) which is supposed to be the Synchronization Object.
we want to use just one Thread pool with any number of thread in such a way that Task of the class First have higher priority to class Second in the Execution. using Countdown latch or any other object how could I implement this problem ?

Comment: should we assume this is Java? Please use tag for language. why do you require only one pool ? And what is the role of this synchronization object ? The more locking you do, the less concurrency you get.

Comment: yes it is in java.